# Wired ethernet no traffic count

Tags: networking, ethernet

My 1000MBit Ethernet doesn't show any traffic count anymore since reinstalling with 14.04. With 12.10 everything was fine. Neither in `ifconfig` nor `gnome-system-monitor` shows any traffic. But the Network is working fine. The wireless network is counting traffic as it should (but it's disabled now)

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet Adresse:192.168.0.xxx  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: xxxx::xxxx:xx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:87586256 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:87586256 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
          RX-Bytes:14139377083 (14.1 GB)  TX-Bytes:14139377083 (14.1 GB)

$ lspci | grep Ethernet
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 08)
05:01.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR5212/AR5213 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in kernel 3.13. It will be fixed with 3.14. There is a bug report on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1292509).

---

#### EDIT

Run `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-utopic` to install backported kernel version 3.16. Reboot and traffic count will work again.